# Do multivariate Householder methods exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

Newton's method can be extended to higher-order versions using Householder's method.

Newton's method can also be extended to the case of multivariate inputs, sometimes called the "Newton-Raphson method."

Do the Householder's methods likewise yield such a generalization, using higher partial derivatives?